# Como ocultar informações sensíveis no Django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, docker, bash

No meu projeto Django tenho algumas variáveis sensíveis, as quais preciso 'escondê-las'.
No geral, as salvo em um arquivo .env e as leio com 
`DADO_SENSIVEL = os.environ.get("DADO_SENSIVEL", default="")`..

Gostaria de entender qual a diferença entre eu salvar essas variáveis no **.env**, no **.bashrc** e no **.bash_profile**

A resposta depende do uso do Docker? Se sim, qual seria a diferença usando e não usando o docker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não entendi completamente a pergunta, por exemplo: não consigo ver o relacionamento do django com o docker nesse contexto, mas vou tentar responder. Se entendi, o que vc quer é ocultar informações sensíveis em um projeto django. Considerando que seja isso vou explicar a minha abordagem (***Eu uso linux***):

Primeiro eu crio um arquivo do tipo `.yaml` que pode ser "parseado" pelo pacote [PyYAML](https://pypi.org/project/PyYAML/), nesse arquivo coloco as informaçẽos sensiveis para serem lidas no `setttings.py` do django, abaixo um exemplo:

```
db:
    default:
        ENGINE: 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2'
        NAME: 'nome-banco'
        USER: 'user-name'
        PASSWORD: 'change-me'
        HOST: 'localhost'
        PORT: '5432'
        OPTIONS: {}

email:
    email_host: 'smtp.<config>.com'
    email_port:  587
    email_host_user: 'no_reply@<email.com>'
    email_host_password: '<your_password>'
    use_tls: True

key: sdn2-%Hey-Jude_take-a-sad-song_and_make-it-better
```

Veja que nesse arquivo são colocadas as informações sobre o banco de dados, envio de email e a chave para a criação de tokens.

Então escolha um lugar para colocar esse arquivo, por exemplo em `/etc/name-app/config.yaml`

Crie uma variável de ambiente que aponte para o local onde esse arquivo estará armazenado (no servidor, faço isso no [gunicorn](https://gunicorn.org/)), no ambiente de desenvolvimento, no meu caso isso pode ser feito com o comando export:

```
export VARNAME='/path/to/file'
```

**Esse comando pode ser colocado no seu arquivo ~/.bashrc, que vc cita.**

Então no arquivo `settings.py` do django, primeiro tento ver se a variável existe no sistema, se sim, carrego o arquivo a partir do caminho que ela aponta e atribuo os valores às variaveis, assim:

```
CONFIG = os.environ.get('VARNAME')
try:
    with open(CONFIG, 'r') as f:
        settings = yaml.safe_load(f)
except IOError as e:
    print("I/O error({0}): {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))
    raise
except:
    print("Erro inesperado", sys.exc_info())
    print("Erro inesperado", sys.exc_info()[0])
    raise

# To send email
EMAIL_HOST = settings['email_host']
EMAIL_PORT = settings['email_port']
EMAIL_HOST_USER = settings['email_host_user']
EMAIL_FROM = settings['email_host_user']
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = settings['email_host_password']
EMAIL_USE_TLS = settings['use_tls']

SECRET_KEY = settings['key']
DATABASES = settings['db']
```

Essencialmente, é isso, não importa se seu servidor ou ambiente de desenvolvimento está na maquina fisica, em uma máquina virtual ou em um container docker.

Se não estiver claro, diga que tento melhorar a resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o python-decouple, com ele é possivel inserir os dados no settings.py.. puxando dados de um arquivo externo .env ou .ini na qual você declara strings constantes como no exemplo abaixo:

```
#nome_do_projeto/setting.py
from decouple import config
DEBUG = config('DEBUG', default=False, cast=bool)#a opção cast declara o tipo.
SECRET_KEY = config('SECRET_KEY')
```

ao invés de:

```
DEBUG=TRUE
SECRET_KEY = "sejalqualforakey"
```

e dentro do arquivo .env:

```
#raiz_do_projeto/.env:
DEBUG=TRUE
SECRET_KEY=sejalqualforakey
```

e caso você precise inserir uma lista por exemplo em ALLOWED_HOSTS:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = config('ALLOWED_HOSTS', default=[], cast=Csv())
```

aqui o cast contem um método Csv que precisa ser importado em:

```
from decouple import config, Csv
```

e no .env:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS=127.0.0.1, .localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

Gosto de usar o [python decouple](https://github.com/henriquebastos/python-decouple) pra fazer isso

Tem um tutorial [aqui](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/2015/11/26/package-of-the-week-python-decouple.html)